# How to refer environment variable inside GitHub workflow?

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions, cicd

I'm trying to read the the GitHub environment variable inside the request json payload while making the curl request but somewhat these variables are not resolving and it gives an error the values I'm trying to read are KEY_VAULT and ACR_PATH:SNAPSHOT_VERSION inside the flow create container web. I've attached the GitHub workflow sample below.

```
name: Pull Request

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [review_requested]

env:
 
  KEY_VAULT: "some vault"
  SNAPSHOT_VERSION: ${{ format('{0}-SNAPSHOT', github.event.number) }}
  GITHUB_ISSUE_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.number }}
  GITHUB_REPO: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
  DEPLOYMENT_NOTIFICATION_URL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SOME_TOKEN }}
  DEPLOYMENT_URL_TOKEN: 123
  ENVIRONMENT: sandbox
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Docker login
        #if: steps.pr-label.outputs.result == 'true'
        uses: azure/docker-login@v1
        with:
          login-server: acr-login.com
          username: user
          password: pwd

      - name: Publish Snapshot To ACR
        #if: steps.pr-label.outputs.result == 'true'
        run: |
          echo steps.pr-label.outputs.result
          echo Publishing to $ACR_PATH:$SNAPSHOT_VERSION
          docker build . -t $ACR_PATH:$SNAPSHOT_VERSION
          docker push $ACR_PATH:$SNAPSHOT_VERSION

      - name: Create Container Web
          #if: steps.pr-label.outputs.result == 'true'
        run: |
            AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: token $DEPLOYMENT_URL_TOKEN"
            CONTAINER_WEB_NAME="CONATINER"
            PROJECT_NAME="tirumalesh-automate"
            REGION="US"
         URL="https://abcd.com/$REGION/$PROJECT_NAME/container-web/$CONTAINER_WEB_NAME"
            PAYLOAD='{
                                 "spec": {
                                   "image": "${{env.ACR_PATH}}:${{env.SNAPSHOT_VERSION}}",
                                   "secrets": {
                                     "key_vaults": [
                                       {
                                         "name": "${{env.KEY_VAULT}}",
                                         "secrets": [
                                           {
                                             "name": "mysql-pwd",
                                             "environment_variable": "mysql_pwd"
                                           },
                                           
                                         ]
                                       }
                                     ],
                                   },
                                 }
                                 }'
            curl --location --request PUT 'https://abcd/us/projects/tirumalesh-automate/resources/container-web/configuration-service' \
            --header "$AUTH_HEADER" \
            --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                        --data-raw "$PAYLOAD"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have single quotes around `PAYLOAD`, which means that it will take the string literally and not expand anything.

Use double quotes and escape the quotes.

```sh
PAYLOAD="{
    \"spec\": {
        \"image\": \"${{env.ACR_PATH}}:${{env.SNAPSHOT_VERSION}}\",
        \"secrets\": {
            \"key_vaults\": [
                {
                    \"name\": \"${{env.KEY_VAULT}}\",
                    \"secrets\": [
                    {
                        \"name\": \"mysql-pwd\",
                        \"environment_variable\": \"mysql_pwd\"
                    },
                    
                    ]
                }
            ],
        },
    }
}"
curl --location --request PUT 'https://abcd/us/projects/tirumalesh-automate/resources/container-web/configuration-service' \
--header "$AUTH_HEADER" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw "$PAYLOAD"
```